# How can I show that if a theory T is closed under extension, then it can be axiomatised using existential sentences?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If M and N are two models and the inclusion M ⊆ N is an embedding,then N is an extension of M.

An existential sentence is a sentence which consists of a string of existential quantifiers followed by a quantifier-free formula.

How can I show that if a first-order theory T is closed under extension, then it can be axiomatised using existential sentences?

I think the proof might involve the method of diagrams, the compactness theorem and even Loewenheim-Skolem theorem, but I don't know how to connect the dots.

Comment: I think [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com) or [cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) are mor suitable websites for such kind of a question.

Comment: @logi-kal Thanks! I will try my luck over there :)